# Creating New Message with default signature using Exchange Web Services

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

Currently a piece of our application creates and saves new mail messages to a user's drafts folder using Exchange Web Services.  We would like to automatically append the user's default signature to these messages when creating them, but I have not been able to find a way to access the signature to append it to the body.  The email message is currently created with the following code:

```
CreateItemType createEmailRequest = new CreateItemType();
createEmailRequest.MessageDisposition = MessageDispositionType.SaveOnly;
createEmailRequest.MessageDispositionSpecified = true;

DistinguishedFolderIdType draftsFolder = new DistinguishedFolderIdType();
draftsFolder.Id = distinguishedFolderIdNameType;
createEmailRequest.SavedItemFolderId = new TargetFolderIdType();
createEmailRequest.SavedItemFolderId.Item = draftsFolder;

MessageType emailMessage = new MessageType();
emailMessage.Subject = subject;
emailMessage.Body = new BodyType();
emailMessage.Body.BodyType1 = bodyType;
emailMessage.Body.Value = body;
emailMessage.Sensitivity = SensitivityChoicesType.Normal;
emailMessage.SensitivitySpecified = true;

createEmailRequest.Items = new NonEmptyArrayOfAllItemsType();
createEmailRequest.Items.Items = new ItemType[1];
createEmailRequest.Items.Items[0] = emailMessage;
```

Any ideas on how to get the current user's default signature and append it to the body the email?

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this?

Comment: I wasn't able to achieve this using the web service.  Since the application in question is a desktop app, I was able to use the answer from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6442747/add-the-default-outlook-signature-in-the-email-generated

Answer (score 3):

The signatures in Outlook are a client-side feature and thus can't be accessed from Exchange Web Services.  In fact I believe the signatures are actually stored in the users profile *on the machine* - I know I have to redo my signature when moving from one machine to another (I'm on Outlook/Exchange 2010).

In Exchange 2010 You can create a [transport rule that can access user information](http://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/corporatesignatures.htm), but there's not a way to use the Outlook signature information that I'm aware of.