# Add the default outlook signature in the email generated

Tags: c#, winforms, outlook-2003

I am using the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application` to generate an email and display it on the screen before the user can send it. The application is a `winform` application coded in `C#` in the `.NET Framework 3.5 SP1` and it is `Microsoft Outlook 2003`. I am using the following code:

```
public static void GenerateEmail(string emailTo, string ccTo, string subject, string body)
    {
        var objOutlook = new Application();
        var mailItem = (MailItem)(objOutlook.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem));        
        mailItem.To = emailTo;          
        mailItem.CC = ccTo;
        mailItem.Subject = subject;
        mailItem.HTMLBody = body;
        mailItem.Display(mailItem);
    }
```

My question is:

**How do i insert/add the default signature of the user who is using the application in the `body` of the email generated?**
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Take a look at the link below. It explains where the signatures can be found in the file system as well as how to read them properly.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vsto/thread/86ce09e2-9526-4b53-b5bb-968c2b8ba6d6

The thread only mentions Window XP and Windows Vista signature locations. I have confirmed that Outlooks signatures on Windows 7 live in the same place as Vista. I have also confirmed that the signature location is the same for Outlook 2003, 2007, and 2010.

Here's a code sample if you choose to go this route. Taken from [this site.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/outlookdev/thread/a05843c5-ac97-4516-93ad-80838622ffb3/)

```
private string ReadSignature()
{
    string appDataDir = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "\\Microsoft\\Signatures";
    string signature = string.Empty;
    DirectoryInfo diInfo = new DirectoryInfo(appDataDir);

    if(diInfo.Exists)
    {
        FileInfo[] fiSignature = diInfo.GetFiles("*.htm");

        if (fiSignature.Length > 0)
        {
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fiSignature[0].FullName, Encoding.Default);
            signature = sr.ReadToEnd();

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(signature))
            {
                string fileName = fiSignature[0].Name.Replace(fiSignature[0].Extension, string.Empty);
                signature = signature.Replace(fileName + "_files/", appDataDir + "/" + fileName + "_files/");
            }
        }
    }
        return signature;
}
```

---

Edit: [See here to find the name of the default signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15800911/programmatically-set-outlook-2013-signature-defaults) for Outlook 2013 or @japel's answer in this thread for 2010.

Comment: Thats the first google result I came across. My question is that is there any way to do the same by the Microsoft Outlook Api. It helps us to specify the sender, receiver and body of the message. Is it anyhow that it can specify us with the default signature of current user in outlook

Comment: @reggie, I'm sorry, I didn't get that from your question. I could be dead wrong (though I haven't been since the last time), but I don't know of a way to do that. The method that I posted seems to be the preferred way. What's your objection to it?

Comment: @reggie, no problem. I tested this on Windows 7 and it worked perfectly!

Comment: the only problem with this method is when the user has more than one signature save. It does not recognize the default one. But I will buy it for now. Thanks for your help. really appreciate it. I believe there is no other way around

Comment: I accomplished this by Displaying the email and then prepending to the body.  As soon as Outlook displays the email, it puts the signature in place for you.  Then you just have to modify the body.  Although I just found this solution and will be definitely taking a closer look at this.

Answer (score 59):

There is a really quick easy way that hasn't been mentioned.  See modified below:

```
public static void GenerateEmail(string emailTo, string ccTo, string subject, string body)
{
    var objOutlook = new Application();
    var mailItem = (MailItem)(objOutlook.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem));        
    mailItem.To = emailTo;          
    mailItem.CC = ccTo;
    mailItem.Subject = subject;
    mailItem.Display(mailItem);
    mailItem.HTMLBody = body + mailItem.HTMLBody;
}
```

By editing the HTMLBody after you display the mailitem you allow for Outlook to do the work of adding the default signature and then essentially copy, edit, and append.

Comment: it should be noted that a) This will actually display the email to the user and b) `mailItem.HTMLBody` will in most cases return a complete html document, so prepending a string to that value may result in invalid html, like `bodyText<html>signature</html>`. http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack is useful for parsing the signature and inserting your text where you want.

Comment: @Tewr concat is not clean but it works well, Outlook seems to be smart enough to correct this.
These mails are well interpreted in Gmail, Outlook webmail and Outlook application.
Also, when looking to HTML source of sent and received mails in Outlook application, HTML is well formed

Comment: +1 This is Amazing! I wish I could a green check mark on this one. It must be done after the mailitem.Display() not before or else it doesn't pull the default sig.

Comment: Really works. But when i do this, I get a popup on the outlook window before the code appends the body content. "A Program is trying to access email address information stored in Outlook" with Allow and Deny buttons. Is it possible to avoid this popup from being showed in the first place. The client has Outlook 2013 and I am using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook (Microsoft Outlook 15.0 Object Library)

Comment: This doesn't work when its an RTFBody and not an HTMLBody.  I tried concatenating and empty byte array to the RTFBody but that throws an out of memory exception...any ideas to get this working on an RTFBody email?  The signature ends up displaying but the body text does not display

Comment: Adding attachments before the `HTMLbody` is set will break this. Add Attachments after if needed.

Comment: Perfect, This should be the accepted answer. Secret to this approach is assigning mailItem.HTMLBody after the mailItem.Display()

Comment: This causes an error for me. Not sure why I cannot call the method. Possibly because of used event handlers in between?

Answer (score 16):

I have had the exact same problem, but was able to solve it with Interop only, and thus get the default signature.

The trick is to call [GetInspector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._mailitem.getinspector%28v=office.12%29.aspx), which will magically set the [HTMLBody](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._mailitem.htmlbody%28v=office.12%29.aspx) property to the signature. Just reading the GetInspector property is enough. I tested this with Windows 7 / Outlook 2007.

Credits to [this blog post](http://geekswithblogs.net/QuandaryPhase/archive/2009/08/07/outlook-automation-without-com-references.aspx) for the solution.

Comment: This works with Windows 8.1 Office 2013 as well.  This is preferable to the other option of displaying the email as we sometimes auto send. Thanks!

Comment: Has this been tested for Outlook 2016?  I don't believe that this works any longer.

Comment: This worked for me with Windows 10 (Fall Creators Update) and Office 2016.

Comment: In Outlook 2022 (under Windows 11) this throws "Sorry, something went wrong" message, but works well if we call the .Close() message on returned inspector (`mailItem.GetInspector.Close(OlInspectorClose.Save)`.

Answer (score 6):

I've found a very easy way to attach the default outlook signature (including images). The trick is to retrieve the body message after calling the GetInspector and concat your message to that.

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop

Dim fdMail As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim oMsg As Outlook._MailItem
oMsg = fdMail.Items.Add(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem)
Dim olAccounts As Outlook.Accounts
oMsg.SendUsingAccount = olAccounts.Item(1)
oMsg.Subject = "XXX"
oMsg.To = "xxx@xxx.com"
Dim myInspector As Outlook.Inspector = oMsg.GetInspector
Dim text As String
text = "mail text" & oMsg.HTMLBody
oMsg.HTMLBody = text
oMsg.Send()
```

Edit 05/03/2021
Be aware that this method seems to fail when using Office 365 build 13530.20440 or higher. You will get a "Sorry, something went wrong. You may want to try again" message. Still waiting for it to be fixed.
If you invoke oMsg.Display() before the oMsg.Send() instead of the getInspector method, it will work, but the user will see the flickering of outlook windows.

Comment: thank you very much @MarçalTorroella . Your Edit part saved my life!

Answer (score 4):

I have got around the problem by mainly being 'sneaky'. If, when you make a new email in Outlook by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>, it inserts the default signature, I store that blank email (with signature) in a temporary string then append that string to another string that has the content in it.

Here is some code to demonstrate it:

```
string s = "";
Outlook.Application olApp = new Outlook.Application();
Outlook.MailItem mail = olApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);

mail.To = "Hi@World.com";
mail.Subject = "Example email";

s = mainContentAsHTMLString + mail.HTMLBody;

mail.Display();
mail.HTMLBody = s;
```

Answer (score 4):

For some reason libraries are made a bit different depending on language installed.
Also a signature can hold a logo-image, wich I do not know why, but it is made in 2 files in 2 different sizes.

```
private string ReadSignature()
    {
        string appDataDir = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "\\Microsoft\\Signatures";
        string signature = string.Empty;
        DirectoryInfo diInfo = new DirectoryInfo(appDataDir);

        if (diInfo.Exists)
        {
            FileInfo[] fiSignature = diInfo.GetFiles("*.htm");

            if (fiSignature.Length > 0)
            {
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fiSignature[0].FullName, Encoding.Default);
                signature = sr.ReadToEnd();

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(signature))
                {
                    string fileName = fiSignature[0].Name.Replace(fiSignature[0].Extension, string.Empty);
                    signature = signature.Replace(fileName + "_files/", appDataDir + "/" + fileName + "_files/");
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            appDataDir = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "\\Microsoft\\Signaturer";
            signature = string.Empty;
            diInfo = new DirectoryInfo(appDataDir);

            if (diInfo.Exists)
            {
                FileInfo[] fiSignature = diInfo.GetFiles("*.htm");

                if (fiSignature.Length > 0)
                {
                    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fiSignature[0].FullName, Encoding.Default);
                    signature = sr.ReadToEnd();

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(signature))
                    {
                        string fileName = fiSignature[0].Name.Replace(fiSignature[0].Extension, string.Empty);
                        signature = signature.Replace(fileName + "_files/", appDataDir + "/" + fileName + "_files/");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (signature.Contains("img"))
        {
            int position = signature.LastIndexOf("img");
            int position1 = signature.IndexOf("src", position);
            position1 = position1 + 5;
            position = signature.IndexOf("\"", position1);
            billede1 = appDataDir.ToString() + "\\" + signature.Substring(position1, position - position1);
            position = billede1.IndexOf("/");
            billede1 = billede1.Remove(position, 1);
            billede1 = billede1.Insert(position, "\\");

            billede1 = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(billede1);

            position = signature.LastIndexOf("imagedata");
            position1 = signature.IndexOf("src", position);
            position1 = position1 + 5;
            position = signature.IndexOf("\"", position1);
            billede2 = appDataDir.ToString() + "\\" + signature.Substring(position1, position - position1);
            position = billede2.IndexOf("/");
            billede2 = billede2.Remove(position, 1);
            billede2 = billede2.Insert(position, "\\");

            billede2 = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(billede2);
        }
        return signature;
    }
```

Getting and inserting the signature:
Global variables:

```
    string billede1 = string.Empty;    // holding image1
    string billede2 = string.Empty;    // holding image2

                        string signature = ReadSignature();
                        if (signature.Contains("img"))
                        {
                            int position = signature.LastIndexOf("img");
                            int position1 = signature.IndexOf("src", position);
                            position1 = position1 + 5;
                            position = signature.IndexOf("\"", position1);

                            //CONTENT-ID
                            const string SchemaPR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID = @"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001E";
                            string contentID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

                            //Attach image
                            mailItem.Attachments.Add(@billede1, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue, mailItem.Body.Length, Type.Missing);
                            mailItem.Attachments[mailItem.Attachments.Count].PropertyAccessor.SetProperty(SchemaPR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID, contentID);

                            //Create and add banner
                            string banner = string.Format(@"cid:{0}", contentID);
                            signature = signature.Remove(position1, position - position1);
                            signature = signature.Insert(position1, banner);

                            position = signature.LastIndexOf("imagedata");
                            position1 = signature.IndexOf("src", position);
                            position1 = position1 + 5;
                            position = signature.IndexOf("\"", position1);

                            //CONTENT-ID
                           // const string SchemaPR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID = @"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001E";
                            contentID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

                            //Attach image
                            mailItem.Attachments.Add(@billede2, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue, mailItem.Body.Length, Type.Missing);
                            mailItem.Attachments[mailItem.Attachments.Count].PropertyAccessor.SetProperty(SchemaPR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID, contentID);

                            //Create and add banner
                            banner = string.Format(@"cid:{0}", contentID);
                            signature = signature.Remove(position1, position - position1);
                            signature = signature.Insert(position1, banner);
                        }
                        mailItem.HTMLBody = mailItem.Body + signature;
```

The stringhandling can be don smarter, but this Works and gave me my sinature
God luck.

Comment: Thank you for this example. My note: Before sending, I delete the attachments that I had to add on imagedata. Because they are sent as attachments in the letter. But if you do not add them, then the images are not displayed when writing a letter.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone looking for an answer after all those years.

In Outlook 2016 **mailItem.HTMLBody** already contains your default signature/footer.

In my case I replied to someone.
If you want to add a message before just do as shown below. Simple.

```
MailItem itemObj = item as MailItem; //itemObj is the email I am replying to
var itemReply = itemObj.Reply();
itemReply.HTMLBody = "Your message" + itemReply.HTMLBody; //here happens the magic, your footer is already there in HTMLBody by default, just don't you delete it :)
itemReply.Send();
```

Answer (score 2):

also I have dealt with this topic for several hours. Finally I stumbled across a very interesting Microsoft support case.

https://support.microsoft.com/de-de/help/4020759/text-formatting-may-be-lost-when-editing-the-htmlbody-property-of-an

The real problem is buried somewhere else:
Microsoft Outlook uses Microsoft Word as the editor. Loss of formatting may occur if the HTML source is verified by the Word HTML module when the item is sent.

To fix the problem, simply load Word.Interopt and use Word as the editor.

Translated with www.DeepL.com/Translator

```
    public static void SendMail(string subject, string message, List<string> attachments, string recipients)
    {
        try
        {
            Outlook.Application application = new Outlook.Application();

            Outlook.MailItem mailItem = (Outlook.MailItem)application.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
            Word.Document  worDocument = mailItem.GetInspector.WordEditor as Word.Document;
            Word.Range wordRange = worDocument.Range(0, 0);
            wordRange.Text = message;

            foreach (string attachment in attachments ?? Enumerable.Empty<string>())
            {
                string displayName = GetFileName(attachment);
                int position = (int)mailItem.Body.Length + 1;
                int attachType = (int)Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue;
                Outlook.Attachment attachmentItem = mailItem.Attachments.Add
                    (attachment, attachType, position, displayName);
            }

            mailItem.Subject = subject;

            Outlook.Recipients recipientsItems = (Outlook.Recipients)mailItem.Recipients;
            Outlook.Recipient recipientsItem = (Outlook.Recipient)recipientsItems.Add(recipients);
            recipientsItem.Resolve();
            mailItem.Display();

            recipientsItem = null;
            recipientsItems = null;
            mailItem = null;
            application = null;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            throw;
        }
    }

    private static string GetFileName(string fullpath)
    {
        string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fullpath);
        return fileName;
    }
```

Have fun with it. Thomas

Answer (score 1):

I have a variant solution to this issue which is worth sharing and is complete for the purpose of sending an email from ANY Outlook Account with the email text merged with ANY signature which you can select.

Assumptions:

You have added a reference to the HtmlAgilityPack which is used to format the HTML content.

As I could find no way (except via the registry) to get the email account signature, this is passed as a text value and can be set as a parameter in the program or by looking in the registry settings for the Outlook Account.

The from account is a valid email account on the system
The signature file was created by Outlook using the html format.

I am sure there are numerous possible improvements to this.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Sends an email from the specified account merging the signature with the text array
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="to">email to address</param>
    /// <param name="subject">subect line</param>
    /// <param name="body">email details</param>
    /// <returns>false if account does not exist or there is another exception</returns>
    public static Boolean SendEmailFromAccount(string from, string to, string subject, List<string> text, string SignatureName)
    {
        // Retrieve the account that has the specific SMTP address. 
        Outlook.Application application = new Outlook.Application();
        Outlook.Account account = GetAccountForEmailAddress(application, from);
        // check account
        if (account == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        // Create a new MailItem and set the To, Subject, and Body properties. 
        Outlook.MailItem newMail = (Outlook.MailItem)application.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
        // Use this account to send the e-mail. 
        newMail.SendUsingAccount = account;            
        newMail.To = to;
        newMail.Subject = subject;
        string Signature = ReadSignature(SignatureName);
        newMail.HTMLBody = CreateHTMLBody(Signature, text); 
        ((Outlook._MailItem)newMail).Send();
        return true;
    }
    private static Outlook.Account GetAccountForEmailAddress(Outlook.Application application, string smtpAddress)
    {

        // Loop over the Accounts collection of the current Outlook session. 
        Outlook.Accounts accounts = application.Session.Accounts;
        foreach (Outlook.Account account in accounts)
        {
            // When the e-mail address matches, return the account. 
            if (account.SmtpAddress == smtpAddress)
            {
                return account;
            }
        }
        throw new System.Exception(string.Format("No Account with SmtpAddress: {0} exists!", smtpAddress));
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Return an email signature based on the template name i.e. signature.htm
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="SignatureName">Name of the file to return without the path</param>
    /// <returns>an HTML formatted email signature or a blank string</returns>
    public static string ReadSignature(string SignatureName)
    {
        string appDataDir = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "\\Microsoft\\Signatures";
        string signature = string.Empty;
        DirectoryInfo diInfo = new DirectoryInfo(appDataDir);
        if
        (diInfo.Exists)
        {
            FileInfo[] fiSignature = diInfo.GetFiles("*.htm");
            foreach (FileInfo fi in fiSignature)
            {
                if (fi.Name.ToUpper() == SignatureName.ToUpper()) 
                {
                    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fi.FullName, Encoding.Default);
                    signature = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(signature))
                    {
                        // this merges the information in the signature files together as one string 
                        // with the correct relative paths
                        string fileName = fi.Name.Replace(fi.Extension, string.Empty);
                        signature = signature.Replace(fileName + "_files/", appDataDir + "/" + fileName + "_files/");
                    }
                    return signature; 
                }
            }
        }
        return signature;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Merges an email signature with an array of plain text
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="signature">string with the HTML email signature</param>
    /// <param name="text">array of text items as the content of the email</param>
    /// <returns>an HTML email body</returns>
    public static string CreateHTMLBody(string signature, List<string> text)
    {
        try
        {
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode node;
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode txtnode;

            // if the signature is empty then create a new string with the text
            if (signature.Length == 0)
            {
                node = HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode.CreateNode("<html><head></head><body></body></html>");
                doc.DocumentNode.AppendChild(node);
                // select the <body>
                node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("/html/body");
                // loop through the text lines and insert them
                for (int i = 0; i < text.Count; i++)
                {
                    node.AppendChild(HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode.CreateNode("<p>" + text[i] + "</p>"));
                }
                // return the full document
                signature = doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;
                return signature;
            }

            // load the signature string as HTML doc
            doc.LoadHtml(signature);
            // get the root node and insert the text paragraphs before the signature in the document
            node = doc.DocumentNode;
            node = node.FirstChild;
            foreach (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode cn in node.ChildNodes)
            {
                if (cn.Name == "body")
                {
                    foreach (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode cn2 in cn.ChildNodes)
                    {
                        if (cn2.Name == "div")
                        {
                            // loop through the text lines backwards as we are inserting them at the top
                            for (int i = text.Count -1; i >= 0; i--)
                            {
                                if (text[i].Length == 0)
                                {
                                    txtnode = HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode.CreateNode("<p class=\"MsoNormal\"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p>");
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    txtnode = HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode.CreateNode("<p class=\"MsoNormal\">" + text[i] + "<o:p></o:p></p>");
                                }
                                cn2.InsertBefore(txtnode, cn2.FirstChild);                                   
                            }
                            // return the full document
                            signature = doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return signature;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return "";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To get/set the user's default signature you can use the windows registry.
Example for Outlook 2010:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Common\MailSettings
Name: NewSignature
Datatype: String
Value: (name of signature file without ending)

Answer (score 0):

Using **GetInspector** causes an exception when implementing an Interceptor using the **Inspectors_NewInspector** event. You will also find that the Signature has yet to be added to the MailItem when the **Inspectors_NewInspector** event is raised.

If you trigger the **Item.Send()** with your own code (e.g. your own button) you will have an Anchor tag `<a>` for both the "Signature" and "Content End". Note these tags are removed from the HTMLBody (in the translation from Word HTML to HTML) if you handle the Outlook ribbon [Send] button click event yourself (as is common for Add-ins).

My solution this is to handle the Item.Open event so that when the Interceptor/Inspectors_NewInspector is created/raised I can then add an Id attribute to the containing `<p>` tag to later use when sending. This attribute stays in the HTML even after sending.

This ensures that whenever the Send is called I can detect in my code the "Signature" or the "Content End" paragraphs.