# C# Set Outlook Default Signature

Tags: c#, outlook, cryptography, signature

I have an application that creates a message signature and deploys it to Outlook. How can I set it to be the default for a new/reply-forward message?
I found out some solutions as below:

- Using Microsoft.Office.Word.Interop object:
   `wordObj.EmailOptions.EmailSignature.NewMessageSignature`

But it initializes an Outlook object too, so I don't want it.

- Setting a value in the registry as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10930040/set-default-signature-outlook)

But in some machines, I am not able to find this registry key.

Has anyone found a stable solution for this problem? Any help would be appreciated so much.

Comment: Added cryptography tag, hopefully with more Outlook knowledge will see the question. If you have already solved it, please post the solution and add @owlstead, happy to vote it up. Try and apply often used tags, signature only has 12 followers, cryptography has 722...

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right avenue.

> But in some machine, I was not able to find this key.

That's because you don't have any profiles configured in Outlook. Or signatures were not set in Outlook. In that case you need to add the required windows registry keys - a REG_Binary named "New Signature" or "Reply-Forward Signature".