# Adding outlook signature from vb.net application

Tags: vb.net, outlook, signatures

I'm writing a simple application that prompts users for their full name, email address and contact information. It then uses this information to generate the HTML code for their corporate signature, ensuring that all signatures are universal in format and layout.

What I want to do is be able to automatically add this signature to outlook once it has been generated. Is this possible and how would I go about it?

Thanks

Jonny

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `Windows 7` and `Outlook 2010`, the user signatures are stored as text files under

```
C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures\
```

or

```
%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Signatures\
```

Your tool could create such files and store them in the *Signatures* directory.
Make sure that you create the signature files in three flavors: 1. Text format, 2. HTML format, 3. RTF.  Otherwise the user would not have a signature for all mail format options.

Apart from supplying the signature files, additional registry settings are needed to actually use the signatures for new mails or for reply mails. A *Microsoft* recipe is [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2691977).

Make sure that the **Disable Signatures** group policy setting is not active.

Comment: Here's how to then select the signature on the default Outlook profile: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23151372/737393