# Preventing link previews in html emails

Tags: html, email, outlook

I am sending out html emails with my company name and website link in the footer. However when viewing these in outlook a preview of the website's content is shown below the link. I have had a search around and it seems possible to prevent these in outlook settings (https://www.codetwo.com/kb/disable-link-preview/) but is there any way to prevent these within the html of the email? The link is a simple 'a' tag:

```
<a href="https://my.website.com" target="_blank">my.website.com</a>
```

Comment: Have you found a solution? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: As link preview is a feature on the reicpient side I don't think you can change this. Maybe you re adding the footer/signature into the body instead of using the signature object? Eugenes answer here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/43897729/1095488) might point the right direction?