# Outlook VSTO - determine correct 'email' signature based on user

Tags: outlook, vsto

I'm writing an Outlook 2010 add-in with VSTO, one part of which will automatically add the correct email signature to a new AppointmentItem.  The issue I've come across is how to determine which signature is the correct one.  For example, I have 2 email signatures set up in Outlook, which have rules on use based on which address my email is coming from.  How can I access these rules?

My issue is not with [finding the signature files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6442747/add-the-default-outlook-signature-in-the-email-generated), but in applying the correct rules based on the user's settings.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this by creating a dictionary object with the key being the email address and the value as the filepath:

```
private Dictionary<string, string> signatureDictionary()
        {
            string sigDataDir = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + @"\Microsoft\Signatures";
            Dictionary<string, string> returnValue = new Dictionary<string,string>();
            Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows Messaging Subsystem\Profiles\Outlook\9375CFF0413111d3B88A00104B2A6676", false);
            string[] str = key.GetSubKeyNames();
            foreach (string s in str)
            {
                Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey subKey = key.OpenSubKey(s, false);
                if (subKey.GetValue("New Signature") != null)
                {
                    returnValue.Add(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(subKey.GetValue("Account Name") as 
                        Byte[],0,(subKey.GetValue("Account Name") as Byte[]).Length - 2)
                        , Path.Combine(sigDataDir,System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(
                        subKey.GetValue("New Signature") as Byte[], 0, (subKey.GetValue("New Signature") as
                        Byte[]).Length - 2) + @".rtf"));
                }
            }
            key.Close();
            return returnValue;
        }
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10952503/493055) to a similar question initially pointed me in the right direction, and figuring out that the "New Signature" key is only populated when a signature has been set for that account.  Undoubtedly there will be situations where this doesn't work, but it sorts it out for my current issue.  Since I use the WordEditor when I'm editing emails in VSTO I use the RTF files in this function, but there are also .HTM and .TXT files in the same directory so you can use those if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the rules by using the code below. You can loop through them and get the rule type and actions

app is the current instance of the Outlook.Application

```
Outlook.Rules rules= app.Session.DefaultStore.GetRules();
foreach (Outlook.Rule r in rules)
{

}
```

Comment: Not really what I'm looking for - this shows all the Folder's rules (like move an email from X to a certain folder), but doesn't cover the signature rules (when I have the signature dialog up, these rules are under the "Default Signature" heading)

Comment: I do not beleive there is a way though the com object.  You can access them via the signatures directory which can be found in %AppData%\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures

Comment: Yes, getting the files themselves is not the problem - finding the *correct* file based on the default signature is the problem.

Comment: This information is held in the registry. HCU\software\Microsoft\windows NT\Current Version\Windows Messaging Subsystem\Profiles\<profile name>\ and then search for "Reply-Forward Signature".  This is where that information is housed and it is a binary key.