# Create Outlook message with Signture in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, outlook

With the code below I can open an open message in outlook and add a subject line and some text in the body.

The problem I have it doesn't keep or use the users signature.

Any thoughts on how to keep or use the signature?

```
        Dim Outlook As Object
        Outlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

        If Outlook IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim omsg As Object
            omsg = Outlook.CreateItem(0)
            omsg.subject = "Your Case Reference is" &
            omsg.body = "Hi" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _

            omsg.Display(False) 
        End If
```

Comment: This might be a [duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6442747/add-the-default-outlook-signature-in-the-email-generated).

Comment: That post is related to C# not Visual Basic code.

Comment: Kenster, it is trivial to convert from C# to VB.Net.  [Check out this website.](http://converter.telerik.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call Display first - that is when the signature is added to the body.

You will the need to merge the HTMLBody property with the signature with your own text. Keep in mind that you cannot simply concatenate 2 HTML strings.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, i added: 

omsg.display() 

Above 

omsg.body = "Hi" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _

Worked a treat, thanks again.